# can not boot when enable secure boot

Tags: secure-boot

windows 8 enterprise x64.
Core i3-2100.
GA-H61M-DS2.
it works well when I enabled fast boot and secure boot.
but when I select load default in uefi bios settings and reboot.
the computer can not boot.
I assume the uefi bios turn off fast boot but still enable secure boot.
please help my computer boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the gigabyte secure boot is password protected so it can not boot.